# Highlighting cells in variant arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Essentially this code takes a bunch of values from a range in one sheet and pastes them into another sheet of the same range dimensions. But this is more of a special paste as this code only pastes into cells that are empty and not ones that already contain values on the other sheet. This is done using variant array (shoutout to @Jeeped for helping me with this) My problem is that I need to highlight cells in red in the destination worksheet that are different from values in the source worksheet when this code is running. This is to prevent fraud as I work for an accounting firm. Thank you so much for your help guys!

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub fill_blanks_from_source()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, aSRCs As Variant, aDSTs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")     '<~~ source
        aSRCs = .Range("C6:R371").Value2
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")     '<~~ destination
        aDSTs = .Range("D9").Resize(UBound(aSRCs, 1), UBound(aSRCs, 2)).Value2
    End With

    For r = LBound(aDSTs, 1) To UBound(aDSTs, 1)
        For c = LBound(aDSTs, 2) To UBound(aDSTs, 2)
            If IsEmpty(aDSTs(r, c)) Then
                aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("D9").Resize(UBound(aDSTs, 1), UBound(aDSTs, 2)) = aDSTs
    End With

End Sub
```

Again, I want to add something that allows the code to read when the cells do not match in value, and then highlight that given cell in red in the destination source along with the pasting of new values in empty cells

I know this is wrong but essentially this is the idea in an abstract thought

```
If IsEmpty(aDSTs(r, c)) = True Then
    aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c)
    ElseIf aDSTs(r, c) <> aSRCs(r, c) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9").Resize(r, c).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    ElseIf aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c) Then
End If
```

Comment: Is the typical replacement 5-10 cells or several hundred?

Comment: its ~ 6000 cells per page and I run this code 110 times (as there are 110 source docs and destination docs) for each store our accounting firm keeps track of, the code works right now great without the highlighting portion in <10 seconds as I have a stong cpu

Comment: Yes, but you are only replacing the blanks. How many blanks in each cycle?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you are pretty close with your abstract thought ...  I think this line would work: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9").Offset(r,c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` The resize won't work, since you are checking cell-by-cell.

Comment: This worked great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the cells is going to be time consuming. By collecting them all with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx), at least the actual formatting operations can be performed at once.

```
Sub fill_blanks_from_source()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, aSRCs As Variant, aDSTs As Variant
    Dim rngBLNK As Range, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim iFirstDestinationRow As Long, iFirstDestinationColumn As Long

    'important to set the first row and column of the destination cells
    'used in calculation of destination address offsets
    iFirstDestinationRow = 9
    iFirstDestinationColumn = 4
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        aSRCs = .Range("C6:AH197").Value2
    End With
    With ws2
        aDSTs = .Cells(iFirstDestinationRow, iFirstDestinationColumn).Resize(UBound(aSRCs, 1), UBound(aSRCs, 2)).Value2
    End With

    For r = LBound(aDSTs, 1) To UBound(aDSTs, 1)
        For c = LBound(aDSTs, 2) To UBound(aDSTs, 2)
            If Not CBool(Len(aDSTs(r, c))) Then
                aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c)
                If rngBLNK Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngBLNK = ws2.Cells(r + (iFirstDestinationRow - 1), c + (iFirstDestinationColumn - 1))
                Else
                    Set rngBLNK = Union(rngBLNK, ws2.Cells(r + (iFirstDestinationRow - 1), c + (iFirstDestinationColumn - 1)))
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    With ws2
        .Cells(iFirstDestinationRow, iFirstDestinationColumn).Resize(UBound(aDSTs, 1), UBound(aDSTs, 2)) = aDSTs
        With rngBLNK
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

If the cells in the destination range are truly blank and not zero-length strings returned by formulas then it would be a simple matter to select them all using the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) and apply formatting before any values are returned to them. However, this has a function limit of 8,192 discontiguous cells and that is getting close enough to your '~6000 cells per page' that I would not recommend its use.